# Retrieving database content by id for page content and by category id for sidebar menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have all pages from my site retrived by id=? with no problem at all. But how can I retrieve together the table contents from the same category id for the sidebar menu?

Main table called `areport`. Secondary tables are called `categories` and `years`. Something like this:

```
areport table
id | category_id | title | message | post_date | and more..

categories table
id | name
```

My coding for retriving content by id:

```
if (!isset($_GET["id"])) {
  header("Location: report.php");
  exit;
}  
$id = $_GET["id"];

try {
  $pdo = db_init();
  $sql = "SELECT 
areport.id AS areport_id,
areport.title AS areport_title,
areport.message AS areport_message,
categories.id AS category_id, 
categories.name AS category_name,
years.id AS year_id,
years.name AS year_name
  FROM areport
  INNER JOIN categories ON areport.category_id = categories.id
  INNER JOIN years ON areport.year_id = years.id
  WHERE areport.id=?";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array($id));
  $areport = $stmt->fetch();

  $title = $areport["areport_title"];
  $message  = $areport["areport_message"];
  $catid = $areport["category_id"];
  $catname = $areport["category_name"];
  $yearname = $areport["year_name"];
```

Will appreciate very much any help.

Comment: do you mean - if there is `$_GET["category_id"]`, you want to retrieve only for that category, otherwise, you just want to retrieve all category?

Comment: how can you retrieve the data of the categories for each post? or how can you retrieve each post for the specific category which is "selected"?

either way I can't understand you're question?

Comment: Hi Tun! I want to retrieve all "areport.title"s from the same "category_id"  into the sidebar menu. For example, if the page retrieves "a.report_message" id=10, so I would like to have all "areport_title"s that belong to the same "category_id" as the "a.report_message" id=10.

Comment: Hi Guy. Sorry for not be clear enough. How can I retrieve all data of  "areport.title"  from the same "category_id" (for the sidebar menu) of the "a.report.message" id that is being retrieved (for the main container).